# Find the center of gravity of a system with three spheres

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, equilibrium

Three spheres are put on a table. The first sphere, whose mass is 1 kg is 20 cm away from the second whose mass is 2 kg and the third sphere is 100 cm away from the first sphere and has a mass of 5 kg: find the center of gravity of the system.

My opinion:

I thought to find the center of mass for each sphere, then do the discrete summation on those coordinates, but I don't have any coordinates.

I thought that the three masses attract each other and create an 8kg mass. It is at the center of gravity, but I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spheres are supposed with homogeneous mass distribution, and also the force of gravity is supposed homogeneous, therefore the CoM coincides with the center of gravity and the center of the sphere, and you can just consider the distance between them:

1 kg --20cm--2 Kg-----80 cm ----- 5Kg

The formula to find the center of mass $\vec{c}$ is:

$$ \vec{c} = \sum_i m_i \vec{r}_i / \sum_i m_i$$

so you can find it calculating:

$(m_1\vec{r}_1+m_2\vec{r}_2+m_3\vec{r}_3)/(m_1+m_2+m_3)$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Where can I get this formula? Is there a way to come to it? And what is r? How can I get it?

Comment: @linus You are missing a parenthesis in your equation. Also, this only works for a linear system (the geometry is not stated in the problem, but should be).

Comment: @LDC3 of course the same formula holds for a system of arbitrary dimensions it's just that the distances should be stated as vectors.

Comment: @linus one should also state that the COM is measured wrt the origin of the coordinate system i.e. the first mass or whatever.